# How long before apps bought on play store on one device, are synched and able to be installed on another device?

Tags: applications

If I buy an app from Google Play Store using my Android phone, how long before Play Store will allow me to download the app on my tablet (using the same Google account) without having to re-buy? Said another way: how long before purchase through Google Play Store are synched and available to all devices on the account?

Thanks

Comment: Where should it be synced to? That check happens server-side AFAIK.

Comment: Usually instantly, It also depends on the license you're granted, sometimes you only buy the rights to use the application on a limited number of devices, usually around 5 devices... sometimes uninstalling from an old device will allow a new device to download it.